# WebGL - canvas is blank when vertices and indices are read from file

Tags: webgl

I am trying to extend an simple example that uses a hard coded set of vertices and indices arrays to display a red square to instead read the vertices and indices from a file and then display the same red square.  The original version works as expected but my update version just displays the blank canvas with a black background. I wrote the vertices and indices arrays out to the console using console.log and they look correct as compared to the expected values. If you have a suggestion of what I am doing wrong or what I need to try I would appreciate the help.  I have included the section of the code where I made the change along with a screenshot of the correct and incorrect display. I've also included a screenshot of the log output from the console. I thought it might be due to the original version only being started by the fact that the init() method was set to the onLoad method for the html page, but I added a event handler to the tab this is in that also calls the same init() method but did not change the result. Thanks.
Edit: added requested additional code below.

```
      // Set up the buffers for the square
      function initBuffers() {

        vertices = [];
        indices = [];

        readObjFile();

        //vertices = [
        //  -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        //  -0.5, -0.5, 0,
        //  0.5, -0.5, 0,
        //  0.5, 0.5, 0
        //];

        // Indices defined in counter-clockwise order
        //indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3];

        console.log(vertices);
        console.log(indices);

        // Setting up the VBO
        squareVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // Setting up the IBO
        squareIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareIndexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // Clean
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
      }
```

readObjFile:

```
      function readObjFile(){

          var input = fs.createReadStream('/home/.../SQUARE.obj');

          var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
            input: input,
            terminal: false
          });

          rl.on('line', function(line){
            processLine(line);
          });

      }
```

processLine:

```
      function processLine(line) {

        if(line[0] == 'v'){
          processVertices(line);
        }

        if(line[0] == 'f'){
          processIndices(line);
        }


      }
```

processVertices:

```
      function processVertices(line){
        var vertex = line.split(" ");
        vertices.push(parseFloat(vertex[1]));
        vertices.push(parseFloat(vertex[2]));
        vertices.push(parseFloat(vertex[3]));
        //console.log("v: " + vertex[1] + " " + vertex[2] + " " + vertex[3]);
      }
```

processIndices:

```
      function processIndices(line){
        var index = line.split(" ");
        indices.push(parseInt(index[1]));
        indices.push(parseInt(index[2]));
        indices.push(parseInt(index[3]));
        //console.log("f: " + index[1] + " " + index[2] + " " + index[3]);
      }
```

SQUARE.obj:

```
v -0.5 0.5 0
v -0.5 -0.5 0
v 0.5 -0.5 0
v 0.5 0.5 0
f 0 1 2
f 0 2 3
```

Pictures showing resulting vertices and indices arrays when read from file (I also checked the same log output for these arrays when using the original hard coded version and it looked the same):

[image]

[image]

The following screenshots show the results for the original version and my read from file version:

[image]

[image]

Comment: change this `console.log(vertices)` to this `console.log(vertices.join(','))` and see if you get the same results in the console. That will help clarify one possible issue. Normally you can't/don't read a file synchronously. Also, please post your code for `readObjFile`

Comment: @gman thanks for taking the time to look at my question. i added the additional source code you requested.  i tried the alternate log format but for some reason it did not show up in the console when I tried that. I've also included the functions readObjFile calls and the contents of the example file being read.  Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is browser code. If so, you can not use `fs.` in the browser. You need to use something like the `fetch()` API. And if you file is of obj format this can help: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-load-obj.html

Comment: @gaitat Thanks for the info about fs and fetch and the link.  I will look at it.